# MySQL QUERY to Find the number of posts per user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Database with the following two tables, USERS, POSTS I am looking for a way to get the count of how many posts(postCount) a user has and also if a user doesn't have any posts the postCount will equal to zero

```
 Users            Posts
 +----+------+    +----+---------+-----------+
 | ID | Name |    | ID | user_id | Name      |
 +----+------+    +----+---------+-----------+
 | 1  | Bob  |    | 1  | 1       | Blargg... | 
 | 2  | Jim  |    | 2  | 1       | Blargg... | 
 | 3  | Jo   |    | 3  | 2       | Blargg... | 
 +----+------+    +----+---------+-----------+
```

In the end I want something like this:

```
 +----+------+ 
 | ID | Count|
 +----+------+
 | 1  |  2   |  
 | 2  |  1   |  
 | 3  |  0   |  
 +----+------+
```

Comment: Exactly same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196399/mysql-find-the-total-amount-of-posts-per-user?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Name, COUNT(p.Name)
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN Posts AS p ON u.ID = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.ID, u.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.ID, COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM Users t1
LEFT JOIN Posts t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.user_id
GROUP BY t1.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
u.id,
count(p.id)
from users u
left join posts p on p.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
order by u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should left join the two tables, in order to include all entries from `users` , even when there are no posts for a user, then a simple order by and an aggregate function to count the posts:

```
select users.id, count(posts.id) from users left join posts on users.id = posts.user_id group by posts.user_id
```